# FB Graph API wall posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a project in which i have implemented Friends invitation using Graph API, i am posting on friend's wall to invite them to my website, this is working fine for one friend invite at a time,i want to invite multiple friends at a time how can i give ID's of multiple friends for inviting? below is my code for posting on wall

```
 FB.ui(
                      {
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: 'My Books',       
                        picture:  'abc.jpg,
                        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                        to: friend_id,
                        description: 'Join.'
                      },
                      function(response) {
                        if (response && response.post_id) {
                           DivMsgText("Friend has been invited");
                        } 
                      }
                    );
```

How can i specify multiple friend's ID in to field? I have array in which friends are appearing but when i specified it in to field,it is not posting on wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not specify multiple ID in that field. When you think that how easy it is to spam, it makes sense. if you want to post on multiple users friend, try graph api:

```
$user_ids = new Array(); //array of user ids;
for($i = 0; $i<$total_ids; $i++)
{  
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$user_ids[$i].'/feed', 'post', array(
    'message' => $status,
    'picture' => $picture,
    'link' => $link,
    'name' => $name,
    'caption' => $caption,
    'description' => $desc,
));
}
```

but the problem is, you cannot post it to too many peoples wall. it's likely to exceed maximum php execution time of 60 seconds.